# iOS Development: How am I mismanaging memory in this code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, memory-management

I just added some code that was taken from the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW20) which shows how to use custom UITableViewCells that are created from a nib.  I'm new to iOS development, so I'm still learning about proper memory management and the code isn't exactly clear to me as to how it works in the first place.  When I run the Allocations instrument, it shows unallocated memory in the code below.  Specifically, it shows the UITableViewCells remain alive after the view controller is popped off the nav stack...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCustomCellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomCell_iPhone" owner:self options:nil];  //<--Allocations instrument complaining about this line
        cell = customCell;
        [self setCustomCell:nil];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

`customCell` is an instance var defined in this view controller, like so...

```
IBOutlet UITableViewCell *customCell;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *customCell;
```

Is there a problem in this code?

Thanks so much for your wisdom!

Comment: Hopefully you have a @property called customCell defined as well?

Comment: Is there a need for the custom Cell to be an IBOutlet?  If you are just looking to load a custom sell you do not need it to be an outlet.

Comment: DerekH, it needs to be an outlet so he can wire up a handle on the cell when the nib is loaded.

Comment: Just to be clear, the issue is that you're leaking these cells? What do you mean by "unallocated"?

Comment: @Firoze, in the Allocations instrument, it shows every one of my UITableViewCells remain alive after the table view controller is popped off the nav stack, which means my memory usage grows by that much memory every time the view controller is loaded. it shows a 95% next to the line of code marked above.  I assume that means 95% of the problem stems from that line of code?

Comment: @Joe, I would check to see if the UITableView is being released properly. If that's hanging around then it will in turn be holding on to those cells.

Comment: FYI about this pattern overall-- Here's what's happening: you're using the ivar as a "staging location" for the cell object you're loading from the NIB. Loading the NIB sets your ivar `customCell` to point to the cell object that is unarchived from the NIB. This just lets you get a hold of it. Since you don't actually care about keeping it as an ivar, you basically say, let me grab a local reference to that for me to use, and then nil out the ivar version of it.

Comment: @Joe: A quick printf-debugging trick is to put an NSLog statement in the -dealloc of a class you care about. In this case, consider whipping up a code subclass of UITableViewCell that corresponds to the one in the NIB, overriding only -dealloc, and logging whether the object goes away. I do this sometimes when I mistrust the tools (which i should trust more, but there you are.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I compared the code from the documentation:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TVCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = tvCell;
    self.tvCell = nil;
}
```

With your code:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomCell_iPhone" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [self customCell];
    [self setCustomCell:nil];
}
```

There seems to be a disparity at the line where you assign `cell`. Apple's example code uses `tvCell`, the **instance variable**, whereas you use `[self customCell]`, the **property getter for the instance variable**. Could that be the cause? Try changing

```
    cell = [self customCell];
```

to

```
    cell = customCell;
```

Comment: thanks, bolt, i tried that and it didn't seem to make any difference.  the Allocations instrument is still reporting that the UITableViewCells remain alive after the view controller is popped from the nav stack.

Comment: thanks for catching that.  it didn't seem to help, but it could affect things elsewhere.  The problem was the UITableView holding the cells wasn't being deallocated correctly.  Thanks again for your help

Comment: @BeachRunnerJoe: No problem, glad you got it tracked down in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good to me, as far as memory is concerned.

What I think is happening is that your view controller is not being released.  In ObjectAlloc, you see the table cells still being retained because they in turn are held by your table view, which in turn is being held by your view controller...

The most common reason why that would be, would be forgetting to set anything that uses your view controller as a delegate to nil in dealloc.

Or possibly, but more unlikely, you are not releasing your table view.  In ObjectAlloc, after you leave the view controller, I would check to see if the view controller itself is also in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Use the debugger. Set a break point in dealloc. Is it being called when you pop the nav controller?